# Dropdown styling issue in opera browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I am new in CSS. I have develop a from in html where I have a drop down, the code of drop down is following

```
<select id="jobTitle" name="jobtitle" class="select-width">
                                <option value="">من فضلك اختر</option>
                                <option value="Employee">موظف محتمل</option>
                                <option value="Supplier">ممون</option>
                                <option value="Investor/Analysis">مستثمر / تحليل</option>
                                <option value="Media">وسائل الإعلام</option>
                                <option value="Media">آخرون</option>
                            </select>
```

In Opera browser my drop down looks like

[image]

I want the below arrow left aligned and this is the case just for Opera browser. How can I do this with css?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add text-align:left; to your css for this particular selector. If it won't help - try: margin-left:0; There could be some pre-set css if you didn't add css reset.